# How to prevent duplicate email submissions in a form (newsletter)

Tags: php, duplicates

I have a simple newsletter form in the footer of my site and I want to prevent visitors from submitting their email twice.

I know there are a number of methods to do this, using a database is one. There are some others using javascript or some server-side scripts, but I'm not sure how to apply those to my newsletter form.

Here is the newsletter code:

```
<form method="post"  action="processnewsrequest.php">

      <fieldset>

           <label for="email">Email:</label>
           <input name="email" type="text" id="email" placeholder="Enter your email" required="required" />
           <input type="submit" class="submit" id="news-submit" value="Join" />

      </fieldset>

</form>
```

The script to process this form is simple. It first lists the email variable; checks to see if an email was entered (or displays an error message); and if successful the newsletter request is sent to the site admin and the visitor gets a message thanking them for joining the newsletter.

What can I do to prevent duplicate email submissions? And how do I apply the methods. I hope I don't have to use a database.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a jQuery code snippet that disables accidental double-clicking of the submit button: when the form is submitted the first time it just disables the submit button.

```
$('form').submit(function(){
    $('input[type=submit]', this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});
```

This assumes the kind of double submit you want to prevent is the '*Oops, I clicked twice*' variety. If your target is the visitors that signs up again while forgetting he's already registered - you'll have to check either the database or wherever is you're storing the email addresses for the newsletter.

Comment: For data storage a database just makes sense - and setting up one doesn't take much of an effort.

Answer (score 0):

You need a way to check the entered email address against the list of email addresses you already have. If those email addresses (with the site admin) aren't stored in a database, or some other way that you can look up then you're out of luck.

Find out from your site admin how they store the email addresses.

Comment: Im the admin of this site (developing it). The emails are sent to an email address.

Comment: Ahh right. I was just going based on your comment in your question saying that they got sent off to the site admin.